# Fortran OMP Parallel Do for a Do While loop

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

As of lately I have been reading and playing around with OpenMP `parallel do`'s in Fortran 95. However, I still have not figured out how the `parallel do` would be used in a code like the one beneath:

```
I=1

DO WHILE I<100
  A=2*I
  B=3*I
  C=A+B
  SUM(I)=C

  I=I+1
END DO
```

Using simply `!$OMP PARALLEL DO` before the do loop and `!$OMP END PARALLEL DO` doesn't seem to work. I have read a couple of things about private and shared variables however I think that each successive loop of the code above is completely independent. Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense to me. Are `A`, `B`, `C` scalars or vectors?

Comment: Please use some actual compilable code. Don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: This `do while` looks like it can be changed to a normal `do` but the code inside is non-sensical or at least inconsistent.

Comment: @vladimirF I edited the code. I think it does make sense now. A,B are simple integers and matrix SUM just stores the sum of A and B on each iteration. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The `parallel do` construct doesn't work with `do while` loops. You need to change the `do while` loop to a standard `DO` loop. This is from the OpenMP 4.0 standard on the `parallel do` construct at https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf, page 59:

• The associated *do-loops* must be structured blocks.

• Only an iteration of the innermost associated loop may be curtailed by a `CYCLE` statement.

• No statement in the associated loops other than the `DO` statements can cause a branch out of the loops.

• The *do-loop* iteration variable must be of type integer.

• The *do-loop* cannot be a `DO WHILE` or a `DO` loop without loop control.

Answer (score 0):

The following example may help with understanding your approach for what you have outlined.
It shows the use of !$OMP and also identifies the thread being used for each iteration of the loop. 
I changed SUM to SUMI to retain SUM as an intrinsic function.
Hopefully you can build on this.

```
 use omp_lib

  real sumi(99), a,b,c
  integer thread_used(0:9), I

    nThreads = omp_get_max_threads ()
    thread_used = 0

!$OMP PARALLEL DO                   &
!$OMP  SHARED  (SUMI,thread_used)   &
!$OMP  PRIVATE (i,a,b,c,iThread)
    DO I = 1,99
      iThread  = omp_get_thread_num  ()
      thread_used(iThread) = thread_used(iThread) + 1
      A=2*I
      B=3*I
      C=A+B
      SUMI(I)=C
    END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

    write (*,*) sum (SUMI)
    do i = 0, nThreads
      write (*,*) i, thread_used(i)
    end do

 end
```